# how to texture an object and keeping the object's color

Tags: texturing, game-engine

I'm trying to to texture an sample object to produce an object with "color" and texture.It work in blender render..[image]

but not in blender game.[image]

I wish someone can help me with this for my game.I'm new with blender :P thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8F1B.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're in solid view. change to GLSL (<kbd>N</kbd>, *Sahding*, *GLSL*) And then click the texture button at the bottom of the screen (<kbd>Z</kbd>) and change to textures (the sphere with checkers.)